# Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition always crashes when signing in

Tags: visual-studio, crash, signing

Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition does not start after login.

Comment: Have you tried using a more updated version? Why do you need to use and old version? Also you should post more information about what operating system and version you are using. Is there any particular error message or log that is generated due to this crash?

Comment: Hello there! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question and include some details: are you getting an error message? Can you find something in the logs? Did you try to submit an issue to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems impossible to upload log files to this bard.

Unfortunately, reorting to developercommunity.visualstudio.com requires log in to Visual Studio. However, this is prevented by he error.